# How to check if a LatLng is valid in Google StreetView using JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement a php service that will take a `$_GET("LAT")` and a `$_GET("LNG")` and verify it against the Google StreetView API **v3** JavaScript if it is valid or not.
If it is, it returns OK, or NOK.

I realize the JS code to accomplish that is:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.121221, 78.121212);
            streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                    //ok
                } else {
                    //no ok
                }
            });
```

I am not being able though to tie everything together, meaning the PHP and JS, so that will work.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

This is the code I came up for far, but it does not work:

```
<?php 
Header("content-type: application/javascript");
?>
<html>
    <head>  </head>
    <body onload="checkValid()">
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

        <script language="text/javascript">
        function checkValid() {
            var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
            var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 100;
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php $_GET("LAT") ?>,<?php $_GET("LNG") ?>);
            streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                    alert('ok');
                } else {
                    alert('not');
                }
            });
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since javascript is only executed in the browser and not on the server, you cannot make a php service, unless you somehow run the javascript on the server, but that is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JS to verify the lat and lng then you need to get the `$_GET` parameters into the JS. Something like:

```
var LAT = '<?=isset($_GET['LAT']) ? $_GET['LAT'] : 91?>';
var LNG = '<?=isset($_GET['LNG']) ? $_GET['LNG'] : 181?>';

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LNG);
streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        //ok
    } else {
        //no ok
    }
});
```

I've used a simple ternary statement asking if the `GET` is available, if it is, then add it to the JS variable, if it's not add a value outside of the range of Lat and Lng. This will cause the Google Maps API to fail automatically.

Comment: Hey Samuel, thanks for this code. I am not being able to make it work yet... I will add the whole code that I have to this question, and maybe you can point what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

True say STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE may help to you find nereast position where exist panarama, below code work, but it requre additional algorithm for  find neares point

```
      var myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(44.293232,-68.294734);
      var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
      var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 1050;  //where we search nearest  panoram
      streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(myLatLng, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
        console.log(":1111111111111111111:",streetViewPanoramaData, status);
        if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
          // ok
      var panoramaOptions = {
        position: streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng, //this is what we found !!!!
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      };

          var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map_pano'), panoramaOptions);
          map.setStreetView(panorama);
        } else {
          // no street view available in this range, or some error occurred
        }
      });
```